# c++ include from another solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, include, solution

i have two VS2013 solutions A and B. My Solution B, containing multiple Projects, was originally compiled to be an executable, but i want to use its functions in solution A, so i changed its compilation to a .lib file.

I added the .lib file from B to my Solution A, but i still have to include the headers.
When i try to include them like this:

```
#include <SolutionB/ProjectB1/header1.h>
```

header1.h tries to include

```
#include "globals.h"
```

globals.h is obviously in the /SolutionB/ProjectB1/ path and can therefore not be found by Solution A.
What is the most simple way to make SolutionA find all the correct headers?
Since SolutionB is quite big i do not want to copy it into the SolutionA folder (which would also make the .lib file obsolete?), neither do i want to rewrite every #include directive in SolutionB.
Is there any possibility to do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: why not simply add the relative include path to the headers in A to the relevant projects of solution B ?

Comment: @Christophe i dont exactly understand how i should do that? Do you mean i should add every path /SolutionB/ProjectB*/ to "Include Directories" under VC++ Directories for my project? Aren't include directories only for includes with '<>' and not with '""'? Would it work if i added the directories to "Source Directories"?

Comment: _"Aren't include directories only for includes with '<>' and not with '""'?"_ Yeah and that's a reason that you should be using `<>`, not `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include` searches through a set of directories for the specified header. Solution B is not part of this list of directories, so `#include` can't find the headers.

In Visual Studio 2015 (should be applicable to all other versions):

1. Go to Project -> ... Properties
2. Go to Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories
3. Under Include Directories you can append the path to the files of Solution B (`(some other path);your\path\to\solution\b`)